# How to count occurrences of a set of values for a range of columns in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that looks something like this:

[image: matrix]

The dataframe is populated with 4 distinct strings: `'00', '01', '10',`and `'11'`. I'm hoping to count each occurrence of the values in each column, so that the data above would return a resulting dataframe that looks something like this:

```
    A   B   C   D   E
00  2   1   3   0   3
01  2   2   0   2   1
10  0   0   1   2   0
11  1   2   1   1   1
```

The original dataframe can be created with this code:

```
dft = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['11', '01', '01', '00', '00'],
                   'B' : ['00', '01', '11', '01', '11'],
                   'C' : ['00', '00', '10', '00', '11'],
                   'D' : ['10', '01', '11', '10', '01'],
                   'E' : ['00', '01', '00', '11', '00'],})
dft
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `value_counts` together with a dictionary comprehension to generate the values, and then use the data to create a DataFrame.

```
>>> pd.DataFrame({col: dft[col].value_counts() for col in dft}).fillna(0)
    A  B  C  D  E
00  2  1  3  0  3
01  2  2  0  2  1
10  0  0  1  2  0
11  1  2  1  1  1
```

Comment: Won't this be the same as `dft.apply(pd.value_counts).fillna(0)`?

Comment: Yes, but appears slightly faster. %timeit dft.apply(pd.value_counts).fillna(0)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.52 ms per loop

%timeit pd.DataFrame({col: dft[col].value_counts() for col in dft}).fillna(0)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.84 ms per loop

Comment: @DSM your suggestion doesn't reorder columns, while Alexander's does (alphabetically, I believe).